# Property 'bordered' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Relevant TypeScript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ng-class-example',
  templateUrl: './ng-class-example.component.html'
})
export class NgClassExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  isBordered: boolean;
  classesObj: Object;
  classList: string[];

  constructor() { } 

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.isBordered = true;
    this.classList = ['blue', 'round']
    this.toggleBorder();
  }

  toggleBorder(): void {
    this.isBordered = !this.isBordered;
    this.classesObj = {
      bordered: this.isBordered
    };
  }
}
```

Corresponding template (the relevant part).

```
<div [ngClass]="classesObj">
  Using object var. Border {{ classesObj.bordered ? "ON" : "OFF" }}
</div>
```

Now I get an error in my .html file (around the attribute .bordered) stating that: "Property 'bordered' does not exist on type 'Object'".

I am new to TypeScript (and also JavaScript) but it seems to me that 'bordered' is defined on the object, so what is going on?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `isBordered` vs `bordered` - there **is** an almost imperceptible difference between the two words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just use `classesObj: Object` in TypeScript because it is assumed to be empty object `{}`. You need to use `any` like

```
classesObj: any;
```

Or if you want to be specific

```
classesObj: {
    bordered: boolean
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you perhaps know if my initial code was allowed in an earlier version of typescript? It seems that I am educating myself with a resource that is outdated.